# From power series to differential equations

Tags: ordinary-differential-equations, power-series

Let $f$ be define by the power series
\begin{align}
f(x)=\sum_{n=0}^\infty   a_n x^n. 
\end{align}
where $f(1)=1$.

Moreover, let $f$ coefficient of power series satisfy 
\begin{align}
\sum_{n=0}^\infty   (n+1) a_{n+1} x^n = \sum_{n=0}^\infty  ( c_k n^k+c_{k-1} n^{k-1}+ \cdots +c_0  ) a_n x^n
\end{align}
for some fixed and given $c_k,...,c_0$. We have to solve for $f$ or find $a_k$'s.

My approach is to solve it by trying to re-write the above as differential equation in terms of $f$.
For example, the first term can be written as
 \begin{align}
\sum_{n=0}^\infty   (n+1) a_{n+1} x^n=  \sum_{n=1}^\infty   n a_{n} x^{n-1}=f'(x)
\end{align}

So we have that 
\begin{align}
f'(x)=   \sum_{n=0}^\infty  ( c_k n^k+c_{k-1} n^{k-1}+\cdots+c_0  ) a_n x^n
\end{align}

Now how to re-write $\sum_{n=0}^\infty  ( c_k n^k+c_{k-1} n^{k-1}+\cdots+c_0  ) a_n x^n$   in terms of derivatives of $f$?

Comment: To clarify, you given the coefficients $c_i$ along with their relationship to the coefficients $a_j$ and asked to determine the coefficients $a_j$?

Comment: @parsiad   Yes, that is correct.

Comment: You have $a_{n+1}/a_n=P(n)/Q(n)$ with $P(n)=c_k n^k+c_{k-1} n^{k-1}+ \cdots +c_0$ and $Q(n)=n+1$. The function $f$ is hypergeometric.

Comment: @AccidentalFourierTransform  Can you please clarify these steps. I am not sure what hypergeometric function is. It be great if you could put the details as an answer.

Comment: It is hard to be more explicit than that without knowing more about the $\{c_i\}$. Do you have any explicit sequence in mind? I don't think you will be able to get a closed-form expression for arbitrary $\{c_i\}$. If you pick a specific example, people might be able to help.

Comment: @AccidentalFourierTransform I had this in mind for a general case when $c_i$ are arbitrary.

Comment: @AccidentalFourierTransform Can you explain a bit more your notation with $P(n)$ and $Q(n)$?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Note that
$$
D_x^j(x^jf(x))=\sum_{n\ge0}a_n n^{(j+1)}x^n
$$
with $n^{(\,\cdot\,)}$ the rising factorial. Thus,
$$\begin{aligned}
\sum_{n\ge0} c_0 a_n x^n&=c_0f(x)\\
\sum_{n\ge0} c_1 n a_nx^n&=c_1\left[(xf(x))'-f(x)\right]\\
\sum_{n\ge0} c_2 n^2a_nx^n&=c_2\left[(x^2f(x))''-3\left[(xf(x))'-f(x)\right]-2f(x)\right]\\
&\cdots
\end{aligned}
$$

Therefore, your function indeed satisfies a linear differential equation of order $k$. Writing it down explicitly for arbitrary $\{c_i\}$ is left as an exercise to the reader. Hint: think of the [Stirling numbers](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Stirling_numbers_of_the_second_kind) of the second kind:

> $$\sum_{n\ge0}c_kn^ka_nx^n=c_k\sum_{j=1}^k S^{(j)}_k x^j f^{(j)}(x)$$

Note also that one may write $f(x)$ as a $_kF_0$ [hypergeometric function](http://mathworld.wolfram.com/HypergeometricFunction.html) whose parameters are essentially the roots of $c_kn^n+\cdots+c_0=0$. Again, for arbitrary $\{c_i\}$ this is as explicit as it gets.

Comment: Can you at least do one more term? So I can better see the pattern.  Also, should I expect a nice formula at the end, or will it be messy?

Comment: @Lisa I wrote down the formula for arbitrary $k$, but you'll have to prove it yourself.

Comment: Great. Thanks a lot. I will try to do this.  I will put the derivation. Do you mind checking it once I write it?  Also, are $S_k^{(j)}$ the Stirling numbers that you mentioned?